# Firebase Module Installation Failled

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I want to install firebase-tools to implement Firebase Cloud Functions. Trying to install the firebase module via npm but always get an error. Tried with many node version such as 6.11.5, 8.9.4 & 9.5.0. All versions are giving same issue. Can you please help me out to resolve this issue.
Node Version- v 9.5.0
npm - v5.6.0
This is the output of the terminal.

```
C:\Windows\system32>npm install -g firebase

grpc@1.9.1 install C:\Users\PankajKapoor\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\fire
base\node_modules\grpc
node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://storage.googleapis.com/g
rpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.9.1/node-v59-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.9.1 and node@9.5.0 (no
de-v59 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python2.7", you can set the
PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_mo
dules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack at PythonFinder. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_mod
ules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\grac
eful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodej
s\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--f
allback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=C:\Users\PankajKapoor\
AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase\node_modules\grpc\src\node\ex
tension_binary\node-v59-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_
node" "--module_path=C:\Users\PankajKapoor\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\firebase\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v59-win32-x64
-unknown" "--python=python2.7"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\PankajKapoor\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase\nod
e_modules\grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v9.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.e
xe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.j
s configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\Panka
jKapoor\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase\node_modules\grpc\src\node\ext
ension_binary\node-v59-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node
--module_path=C:\Users\PankajKapoor\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase\no
de_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v59-win32-x64-unknown --python=py
thon2.7' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\PankajKapoor\A
ppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre
-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:160:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/chi
ld_process.js:220:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Pank
ajKapoor\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase\node_modules\grpc\nod
e_modules\node-pre-gyp\bin\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--l
ibrary=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\PankajKapoor\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\fir
ebase\node_modules\grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v9.5.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.39
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node
_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build
--library=static_library --module=C:\Users\PankajKapoor\AppData\Roaming\npm\nod
e_modules\firebase\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v59-win32-x6
4-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\PankajKa
poor\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extens
ion_binary\node-v59-win32-x64-unknown --python=python2.7' (1)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.9.1 install: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library =static_library
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.9.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\PankajKapoor\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-02-19T15
_34_36_592Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Are you sure that python is there? This message should be a good hint: `Can't find Python executable "python2.7", you can set the
PYTHON env variable.`

Comment: i had tried using Python but its not been able to download the link node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): storage.googleapis.com/g rpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.9.1/node-v59-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz

Comment: First install python, make sure it's working by checking the version, then try a minimal ("Hello World") example to see it's really working.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to install Python

[Python.com - downloads for Windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)

Comment: i had tried using Python but its not been able to download the link node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://storage.googleapis.com/g
rpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.9.1/node-v59-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying, here. The installer for Windows is an EXE. Are you downloading the wrong file, or is the installer unsuccessfully attempting to download something?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this command

npm install firebase --force